# Convert date-time format for use in xts

Tags: r, xts

I am trying to convert my data into an xts but I keep getting a "order.by requires an appropriate time-based object" error so I am trying to convert my date time into the correct format.

My data looks like this:

```
 Date      Time      Value
 20090202  9:30      1
 20090202  9:31      2
 20090202  9:32      3
 20090202  9:33      4
 20090202  9:34      5
 20090202  9:35      6
```

I have done this as well: data.frame(cbind(theData$Date, theData$Time)) which yields:

```
    1         2          
 20090202    09:30
 20090202    09:31
 20090202    09:32
 20090202    09:33
 20090202    09:34
 20090202    09:35
```

how to I merge these into one columnn so its:

```
       1
 20090202 09:30
 20090202 09:31
 20090202 09:32
 20090202 09:33
 20090202 09:34
 20090202 09:35
```

so that I can then put it into an xts()

Comment: Both of your code samples of what you tried have syntax errors. Can you please post the actual commands you ran?

Answer (score 7):

You just need to use `paste` on the date and time column, then call `as.POSIXct` on that.

```
theData <- read.table(text="Date      Time      Value
 20090202  9:30      1
 20090202  9:31      2
 20090202  9:32      3
 20090202  9:33      4
 20090202  9:34      5
 20090202  9:35      6", header=TRUE, as.is=TRUE)
theData$DateTime <- paste(theData$Date, theData$Time)
xts(theData$Value, as.POSIXct(theData$DateTime, format="%Y%m%d %H:%M"))
```

Comment: This produces error: order.by requires an appropriate time-based object. The date and time merges successfully. But the as.POSIXct is not wokring for some reason.

Comment: If this answer resolves your question, please select it as the right answer by clicking on the tick arrow to the left of the answer. This is how Stack Overflow works.

Comment: Watch out with as.POSIXct without specifying the timezone argument! This may produce unexpected results. Use tz="GMT" if you want to avoid your datetimes to be converted to another timezone. Or use the lubridate package.