# How to change imported CSV to xts in R

Tags: r, csv, import, xts

I have some data which has been imported from an excel csv file.

How do I get that data as an xts?

```
         Date    Open    High     Low   Close
1  2017-09-01 1.29360 1.29951 1.29052 1.29495
2  2017-09-03 1.29600 1.29660 1.29444 1.29535
3  2017-09-04 1.29536 1.29643 1.29124 1.29300
4  2017-09-05 1.29306 1.30440 1.29088 1.30331
5  2017-09-06 1.30331 1.30820 1.30181 1.30471
6  2017-09-07 1.30472 1.31381 1.30325 1.31319
7  2017-09-08 1.31319 1.32239 1.31233 1.31945
8  2017-09-10 1.31816 1.31978 1.31736 1.31769
9  2017-09-11 1.31769 1.32223 1.31593 1.31764
10 2017-09-12 1.31766 1.33145 1.31703 1.33097
11 2017-09-13 1.33096 1.33286 1.31836 1.32040
12 2017-09-14 1.32039 1.34055 1.31501 1.33955
13 2017-09-15 1.33955 1.36159 1.33922 1.35871
14 2017-09-17 1.35579 1.36029 1.35579 1.35921
15 2017-09-18 1.35921 1.36181 1.34646 1.35176
16 2017-09-19 1.35176 1.35515 1.34683 1.35178
17 2017-09-20 1.35178 1.36573 1.34517 1.34914
18 2017-09-21 1.34914 1.35861 1.34706 1.35761
19 2017-09-22 1.35760 1.35955 1.34496 1.34935
20 2017-09-24 1.34872 1.35339 1.34832 1.35261
21 2017-09-25 1.35262 1.35706 1.34308 1.34816
22 2017-09-26 1.34816 1.35139 1.34094 1.34385
23 2017-09-27 1.34386 1.34389 1.33634 1.33753
24 2017-09-28 1.33754 1.34551 1.33427 1.34159
25 2017-09-29 1.34160 1.34258 1.33497 1.33963
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Use `dput` to show your data.

Answer (score 1):

try [Convert date-time format for use in xts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18261160/convert-date-time-format-for-use-in-xts) for more info, but this works on a subset of your data.

```
library(xts)
df = read.table(file = "Your table here", header = TRUE)

df$[row_counts] = NULL ## Remove if row counts are imported in the first column (i.e. the 1 2 3 4....)

## Save the date in a separate identifier as character
dates = as.character(df$Date)

## Remove date values from table
df$Date = NULL

## Create xts object with hyphens to account for your format
my_xts_object = xts(df, as.POSIXct(dates, format="%Y-%m-%d"))
```

Comment: I agree about the V1 column. Also in the current data the na.omit in this dataset is doing nothing and is removed in the edit. The object is saved to the my_xts_object.

Answer (score 1):

```
my.dat <-   read.table(text=   "Date    Open    High     Low   Close
1  2017-09-01 1.29360 1.29951 1.29052 1.29495
2  2017-09-03 1.29600 1.29660 1.29444 1.29535
3  2017-09-04 1.29536 1.29643 1.29124 1.29300
4  2017-09-05 1.29306 1.30440 1.29088 1.30331
5  2017-09-06 1.30331 1.30820 1.30181 1.30471
6  2017-09-07 1.30472 1.31381 1.30325 1.31319
7  2017-09-08 1.31319 1.32239 1.31233 1.31945
8  2017-09-10 1.31816 1.31978 1.31736 1.31769
9  2017-09-11 1.31769 1.32223 1.31593 1.31764
10 2017-09-12 1.31766 1.33145 1.31703 1.33097
11 2017-09-13 1.33096 1.33286 1.31836 1.32040
12 2017-09-14 1.32039 1.34055 1.31501 1.33955
13 2017-09-15 1.33955 1.36159 1.33922 1.35871
14 2017-09-17 1.35579 1.36029 1.35579 1.35921
15 2017-09-18 1.35921 1.36181 1.34646 1.35176
16 2017-09-19 1.35176 1.35515 1.34683 1.35178
17 2017-09-20 1.35178 1.36573 1.34517 1.34914
18 2017-09-21 1.34914 1.35861 1.34706 1.35761
19 2017-09-22 1.35760 1.35955 1.34496 1.34935
20 2017-09-24 1.34872 1.35339 1.34832 1.35261
21 2017-09-25 1.35262 1.35706 1.34308 1.34816
22 2017-09-26 1.34816 1.35139 1.34094 1.34385
23 2017-09-27 1.34386 1.34389 1.33634 1.33753
24 2017-09-28 1.33754 1.34551 1.33427 1.34159
25 2017-09-29 1.34160 1.34258 1.33497 1.33963",
 header=TRUE, colClasses=c("integer","Date", rep("numeric", 4) ) )
```

Then convert to xts class which is a matrix and an index, so you do need to remove the date column from the object passed as `x`.

```
my.xts <- as.xts(my.dat[-1], order.by=my.dat[[1]])
str(my.xts)
#-----------
An ‘xts’ object on 2017-09-01/2017-09-29 containing:
  Data: num [1:25, 1:4] 1.29 1.3 1.3 1.29 1.3 ...
 - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  ..$ : NULL
  ..$ : chr [1:4] "Open" "High" "Low" "Close"
  Indexed by objects of class: [Date] TZ: UTC
  xts Attributes:  
 NULL
```